# Passing props from a component and the components in a slot

Tags: svelte

A responsive NavBar component uses NavLink components like this:

```html
<script>
  import NavBar from './nav/NavBar.svelte';
  import NavLink from './nav/NavLink.svelte';
  let barsMenu = false;
</script>

<NavBar logo="LOGO" bind:barsMenu={barsMenu}>
  <NavLink text="About" barsMenu={barsMenu}></NavLink>
  <NavLink text="Contact" barsMenu={barsMenu}></NavLink>
</NavBar>
```

The NavLink components require the barsMenu prop. The NavLink components are part of the NavBar slot like this:

```html
<script>
  export let logo = '';
  export let barsMenu = false;
</script>

<div class="navbar" class:responsive="{barsMenu}">
  <a class="logo" href="javascript:;">{logo}</a>
  <slot></slot>
  <a class="bars" href="...." on:click="{() => barsMenu = !barsMenu}">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Is it possible for the NavBar component to pass the barsMenu prop straight down the slot to the NavLink components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the prop in the `slot` tag:

```html
<slot barsMenu={ barsMenu }></slot>
```

Then use the `let:` directive in the parent tag:

```html
<NavBar logo="LOGO" let:barsMenu={ barsMenu }>
```

[See the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#slot_let)

Comment: Thnx. I missed the : after the let:... before.